# How to send image file from local machine to server using jquery ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have an html form with input type = file, I have a link to API to store images to cloud. In this feature, a user can upload a file from his local machine and upload it to the server. The server returns the cloud url of the uploaded image. In postman it is working fine, but when using with jquery I am not able to figure out how to accomplish this. In postman There are several parameters set like filename, tag and employeeID. In file name field there is choose file button and form-data radio button is checked.

This is my jquery code so far

```js
$("#test-btn").on("click", function() {
$.ajax({
  url: 'myURL/external/upload',
  type: 'POST',
  headers: {
    "appID": "some value",
    "version": "some value",
    "empID": "some value",
    "contentType": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
  },
  data: new FormData($("#test-form")),
  processData: false,
  contentType: false,
  success: function() {
    console.log(data)
  },
  error: function(e) {
    console.log(e)
  }
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" name="upload-image" id="test-form">
  <input type="file" name="filename" />
  <input type="text" name="tag" value="some value" />
  <input type="text" name="empID" value="some value" />
</form>
<button id="test-btn">make</button>
```

I've replaced the confidential fields with dummy values.

Comment: try removing `"contentType" : "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"` this line from headers

Comment: any errors in console?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I upload files asynchronously?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/166221/how-can-i-upload-files-asynchronously)

Comment: use `data : new FormData($("#test-form")[0])` or `data : new FormData(document.getElementById('test-form'))`

Comment: console says : data is not defined.
removing the content type has no effect.
in postman we have a body parameter which has key value pairs. In first field there is a key: filename and value: choose file

Comment: and improve this: `success : function(data){console.log(data)}`

Comment: FormData is not supported in IE until version 10. FYI

Answer (score 0):

```
$("form#test-form").submit(function(){

    var formData = new FormData(this);

    $.ajax({
        url : 'myURL/external/upload',
        type : 'POST',
        data: formData,
        async: false,
        // your other config, params
        success : function(){console.log(data)},
        error : function(e){console.log(e)}
    });

    return false;
});
```

or you can try:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" name="upload-image" id="test-form" action="myURL/external/upload">
  <input type="file" name="filename" />
  <input type="text" name="tag" value="some value" />
  <input type="text" name="empID" value="some value" />
</form>
<button id="test-btn">make</button>

$("form#test-form").submit(function() {
    var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);
    $.post($(this).attr("action"), formData, function() {
        // success    
    });
    return false;
});
```

Comment: `success : function(){console.log(data)}` still `data` is undefined!

Comment: Have you check server side that request have been processed or not ?